# How to remove everything except first column from text file in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge text file ( 375K lines ). All I want is the first column of the text file. I am using notepad++. How can I remove everything except that first column?

Deleting using column select is impossible in such file. I think regex can help me or may be some plugin.

**Edit**
@Bolt: Column: Consider this as first 12 characters or *[space] then numbers then [space]*

Comment: @BoltClock As this is fixed length file i can say zap everything after 12 character from every line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for

```
^(............).*
```

and replace with `\1`

Turn on regular expression mode.

`^` match the start of the row

`(............)` matches 12 characters (no matter what) and stores it in `\1`

`.*` matches everything else in the row that will be removed.

Comment: On a file with 375k lines you may have to wait, but I think Notepad++ can handle it.

Answer (score 6):

To use column-mode select, you can use `Alt-Shft-Arrow keys` or `Alt + Left mouse click`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: you can select a specific column that way and then cut it

Answer (score 1):

Select the block consisting of your first column using ALT+SHIFT and cursor keys or ALT+Mouse.

Copy the Block (CTRL+C)

Select All (CTRL+A)

Paste the copied Block (CTRL+V)

Done